# Look up local variable in function called by do.call

Tags: r, do.call

I have a function that is supposed to use a value based on the environment it is called in:

```
Foo <- function(a) {
  return(a + b)
}
```

In the global environment I can now simply do

```
b <- 1
Foo(2)
# 3
```

The real function will take a list of arguments so I'm using do call, easy enough:

```
do.call(Foo, list(a = 2)
# 3
```

Running this in `local` blocks (or `test_that` blocks for that matter) this doesn't work the way I want it to (either way).

```
local({
  b <- 3
  print(Foo(2))
  print(do.call(Foo, list(a = 2)))
})
# [1] 3
# [1] 3
```

This returns `3`, I want `5`. Had i not defined or deleted the global `b` the function would fail because it cannot find the symbol.

I tried supplying different environments to the `do.call` approach (`environment()`, `parent.env()`,...) using `quote = TRUE` and without but to no avail.

Is there a way for force `Foo` to look up variables in the local block by passing it as an environment?

Comment: you can specify `, envir = .GlobalEnv)` or you can have an `envir` argument in the function so that it can check only in that environment

Comment: When you create a function and there is an undefined argument, the function looks for that argument in the environment where the function was created, in your case `.GlobalEnv`. When you run `local ({...})` the `Foo` function will still look for the `b` argument in the environment where it was defined, that is, `.GlobalEnv` again.

Comment: Thanks all for your input. As Marco described nicely the function is looking for variables in the environment where it was defined, I'd like to look in the environment it was called in. The proposed approaches force local to work in .GlobalEnv thus still working where it was defined. This defeats the purpose of local and I think won't solve the issue that it doesn't work in test_that where I cannot supply such an argument.. I do appreciate the comments though as the local envir variable was something I hadn't considered yet. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Since b is not defined in Foo, Foo will look for b in the environment in which Foo was defined, not the environment in which it was called.

You can redefine Foo's environment.  This will make a copy of Foo such that free variables in it will be looked up in the local environment. No packages are used.

```
local({
    b <- 3
    environment(Foo) <- environment()
    print(Foo(2))
    print(do.call(Foo, list(a = 2)))
    
})
## [1] 5
## [1] 5
```

**2)** If it is ok to modify Foo then other possibilities are to modify it by passing b as an additional argument or passing an environment as an additional argument and have Foo evaluate b in that environment.

```
Foo2 <- function(a, b) {
  return(a + b)
}
local({
    b <- 3
    print(Foo2(2, b))
    print(do.call(Foo2, list(a = 2, b = b)))
})
## [1] 5
## [1] 5
```

**3)** or

```
Foo3 <- function(a, envir = parent.frame()) {
  return(a + envir$b)
}
local({
    b <- 3
    print(Foo3(2))
    print(do.call(Foo3, list(a = 2)))
    
  })
## [1] 5
## [1] 5
```

**4)** A variation of the above that only involves modifying the signature of Foo but not its body is the following (or use `get("b", parent.frame())` if you want to allow it to look into the ancestors of the parent frame as well).

```
Foo4 <- function(a, b = parent.frame()$b) {
  return(a + b)
}
local({
    b <- 3
    print(Foo4(2))
    print(do.call(Foo4, list(a = 2)))
  })
## [1] 5
## [1] 5
```

**5)** Another approach is to inject a statement into Foo using `trace` and then remove it afterwards.

```
local({
  b <- 3
  on.exit(untrace(Foo))
  trace(Foo, bquote(b <- .(b)), print = FALSE)
  print(Foo(2))
  print(do.call(Foo, list(a = 2)))
})
## [1] 5
## [1] 5
```

**6)**  If we wrap the body of Foo in eval.parent(substitute({...})) that will effectively inject it into the caller giving it access to b.  Also see Thomas Lumley article starting on page 11 of [R News 1/3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-3.pdf) .

```
Foo6 <- function(a) eval.parent(substitute({
  return(a + b)
}))
local({
  b <- 3
  print(Foo6(2))
  print(do.call(Foo6, list(a = 2)))
})
## [1] 5
## [1] 5
```

**7)** This is really the same as (6) under the hood except it wraps it nicely.  This is the only one here that uses a package.

```
library(gtools)

Foo7 <- defmacro(a, expr = {
  return(a + b)
})
local({
  b <- 3
  print(Foo7(2))
  print(do.call(Foo7, list(a = 2)))
})
## [1] 5
## [1] 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As mentioned in the documentation `local` creates a local variable to evaluate all the expressions their. Would you please tell me why my second code also changes the value of `b` in the global environment?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 3) is the approach I've been trying out so far to no succes. I hadn't considered 1) yet. I'm confident one of the two has to be the right approach, I just need to get it to work with the actual code. My hunch is that `Foo3` would be "proper" whereas changing the environment on the fly seems more hacky but may help as a last resort

Comment: @Anoushiravan, I think you meant to place this comment under your answer since it relates to your answer rather than mine.  In any case, the second answer in your answer tells it to evaluate the body of local in the current environment, i.e. in the global environment, and the first line of the body is `b <- 3` but assigning 3 to b in the global environment clobbers b.

Comment: Have added some more alternatives.

Comment: Thanks so much, very interesting. What's surprising to me is that none of the approaches use the `envir` parameter of `do.call` I was confident it would require that at first but the more I tried the more I realized the nuances about what the argument does and doesn't do

Answer (score 2):

You should use the complex assignment operator `<<-`, since you want to change the value of `b` in the parent environment of the function's execution environment:

```
library(rlang)

local({
    b <<- 3
    print(Foo(2))
    print(do.call(Foo, list(a = 2)))
    list(env = env_parent(current_env()))  # I added this so it becomes clear that this is the child of Global environment. You can omit it if you like. 
  })

[1] 5
[1] 5
$env
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

I read your description again and saw you wanted your function to be evaluated in in the local environment of `local`. So just as my friends suggested:

```
local({
    b <- 3
    print(Foo(2))
    print(do.call(Foo, list(a = 2)))
    
  }, envir = current_env())

[1] 5
[1] 5
```

Comment: Either of those will clobber the b in the global environment making it equal to 3.

Comment: About the first one I explicitly wanted to change the value `b` in the Globalenv because I misread the question and thought the desired output is to get two `5`s. But then I realized he intended for the data to be self-contained. I don't know why I precisely set the `envir` argument to `current_env` and it again changed the value in the Globalenv.

Comment: Thank you. As pointed out this will modify globals, I failed to stress this enough in the OP but I want to avoid this and instead make the function know where to look rather than moving the things that are looked for around. I do appreciate the answer though as i hadn't considered the envir parameter to local yet. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure @G.Grothendieck idea of changing `foo`'s environment is the one you were looking for.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you very much indeed for your explanation. I really learned a valuable lesson today.

Comment: @Anoushiravan, The construct in your answer could be desirable in certain cases. For example, suppose  you wanted to increment a variable without explicitly passing it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you I understand. The thing that confused me was that when I set the `envir` function to `current_env` , `local` function no longer creates its so-called new empty environment and instead use the Global Environment. Thank you so much again for taking time out to answer my questions.